# How to access the iCloud non-default Outlook Folders with Visual Basic VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, icloud, contacts, basic

This is my very first post and I'm not a programming expert as will quickly be apparent. Please be gentle.

I created a program (using Visual Basic 2010 express) that, among other things, would populate a text box with the "Notes"/"Body" of a contact I select based on the "CustomerID" value of each contact in Outlook.

It works perfectly for the default "Contacts" and its subfolder "Contacts-SubCategory" under Outlook's "My Contacts" group shown here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQSG4.png)
using the following code (the code includes Calendar/appointment items I think I can adapt with a syntax solution for contacts so those can be ignored, I hope):

```
Public Class CustomOutlookInterface2
Private SQL As New DatabaseControl

Private ol As New Outlook.Application
Private olns As Outlook.NameSpace = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Private olContactFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = olns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts).Folders("Contacts-SubCategory")
Private olCalendarFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = olns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar)

Private olContactItems As Outlook.Items = olContactFolder.Items
Private NewContact As Outlook.ContactItem
Private AppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
```

However, I recently downloaded "iCloud for Windows" to keep everything synchronized and noticed that it added a new group in Outlook called "iCloud" and moved contact entries into newly created "Contacts in iCloud" and "Contacts-SubCategory in iCloud" (shown in same picture above). I've made numerous attempts to adapt the previous working code to direct it to the iCloud folder. The closest I've come is...

```
    Private ol As New Outlook.Application
Private olns As Outlook.NameSpace = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Private olContactFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = olns.Folders.Item("iCloud")
```

The above doesn't cause an error. But, it also results in "string not found" when I use the following

```
    Dim query As String = "[CustomerID]='" & CustID & "'"

    NewContact = olContactItems.Find(query)
```

where "query" is the number I assigned to the contact and stored in the Customer ID field

Based on the flat spots on my forehead from banging my head on the desk, I think it boils down to the syntax of identifying the iCloud group then the "Contacts in iCloud" folder then the "Contacts-SubCategory in iCloud" subfolder.
In windows pathing equivalent "iCloud\Contacts in iCloud\Contacts-SubCategory in iCloud\

I can't tell you how much I'd appreciate any help. My desk is threatening to call the cops for all the headbutts I've given it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. I was going to delete the question altogether since it has not been addressed by anyone yet. However, I decided to post my solution in case it helps someone else.

In Outlook, the Contacts screen looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAYFF.png)

My mistake was not understanding that when iCloud for Windows created the iCloud folder it also created the “Contacts-SubCategory” as a subfolder of Contacts (it doesn’t visual look like a sub-folder). Also, the “…in iCloud” suffix shown in Outlook is NOT part of the name needed to identify the folder in code. The code that worked for me to drill down on the “…SubCategory” folder was:

```
Private olContactFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = olns.Folders.Item("iCloud").Folders("Contacts").Folders("Contacts-SubCategory")
```

Without the "...in iCloud" suffix that appears in Outlook. I hope this helps any other inexperienced folks like me. I suffered enough for all of you in trying to solve this as a self-taught rookie. Hopefully you found this post quickly before giving up as I almost did.